# How can I fix this "luarocks make" error when compiling a local torch7 package?

Tags: cmake, torch, luarocks

I am trying to building a package written in torch7(C,cuda,lua) from github [spectral-lib](https://github.com/mbhenaff/spectral-lib)(Ubuntu 14.04, cuda 7.0, torch7 installed). I use this command to build it:
`luarocks make --local`.

However, strange errors occurred as below:

```
...
Scanning dependencies of target spectralnet
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/spectralnet.dir/cuda/cufft.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared module libspectralnet.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcufft
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libspectralnet.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/spectralnet.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can find that "`libcufft.so`" is in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`.
Maybe this error is related to the CMakeLists.txt, but I'm not familiar with it. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Do you have your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable set up to include /usr/local/cuda/lib64?

Comment: You may also want to check the libcufft.so symlink and make sure it's referencing a version of the cuda fft library you actually have installed in lib64. I've seen it get broken occasionally after driver updates.

Comment: My LD_LIBRARY_PATH has /usr/local/cuda/lib64. Anyway, I've solved this problem by modifying the CMakeLists.txt. The author's CMakeLists.txt doesn't work for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it. you should post the modifications you made to the CMakeLists.txt as an answer in case other people run into the same issue in the future.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by modifying the CMakeLists.txt. I copy `libcufft.so` to ./cuda and add:

```
SET(PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libcufft.so )
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/net/wanggu/spectral-lib/cuda)
```

The author's CMakeLists.txt may have some problem with the directions of cuda dynamic libraries. There may exist some better solutions, but this is a temporary solution for now.